# How do I get a bytes::bytes::Bytes from a std::string::String?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to invoke an AWS Lambda function using the Rusoto library. The request has a JSON-encoded payload which I currently have as a String, but the library insists on a `bytes::bytes::Bytes` struct for this. I haven't been able to find a way to convert the String to the Bytes (not the most googleable thing in the world) - can anyone help me out? Thanks.

```
expected struct `bytes::bytes::Bytes`, found struct `std::string::String`
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Bytes`](https://docs.rs/bytes/1.0.1/bytes/struct.Bytes.html) implements [`From`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/convert/trait.From.html)/[`Into`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/convert/trait.Into.html) for [`String`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/string/struct.String.html) to allow conversion from strings to the bytes representing that string in [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8):

```rust
use bytes::Bytes;
fn main() {
    let string = "démonstration".to_string();
    println!("{:?}", string); // "démonstration"
    let bytes: Bytes = string.into();
    println!("{:?}", bytes); // b"d\xc3\xa9monstration"
}
```

[Try it in the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f3bf56875a29331656f343e864b37654)